# I am using Antd Form, how to write a custom FormItem children component type definition using typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I have written a simple demo for this question.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-z0nf68?file=/src/CustomInput.tsx

I know `value` and `onChange` is inner props `FormItem` would pass to the children, so I think I do not need to define them at my `CustomInput` type. I think maybe I could extend something like FormItemProps, But it seems not to work. So I want to ask this question here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Input, InputProps } from "antd";

interface CustomInputProps extends InputProps {
  text: string;
}

const CustomInput = ({ text, ...rest }: CustomInputProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{text}</div>
      <Input {...rest} />
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomInput;
```